# Fastest way to connect with MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

I just wondered what the fastest way to connect to MySQLi is? I have yet to find a stackoverflow post on this, if there is even a fastest way or if every way is faster, I really want to milk the speed for all it is with my application.

Comment: `$con = new MySQLi(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE)` What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a [HandlerSocket](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/handlersocket.html).

- HandlerSocket is a MySQL plugin that implements a NoSQL protocol for MySQL.
- Allows applications to communicate more directly with MySQL storage engines, without the overhead associated with using SQL.

From [the docs](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/handlersocket.html):

> Once HandlerSocket has been downloaded and installed on your system,
>   there are two steps required to enable it.
>
> First, add the following lines to the [mysqld] section of your my.cnf
>   file:
>
> ```
> loose_handlersocket_port = 9998
>   # the port number to bind to for read requests
> loose_handlersocket_port_wr = 9999
>   # the port number to bind to for write requests
> loose_handlersocket_threads = 16
>   # the number of worker threads for read requests
> loose_handlersocket_threads_wr = 1
>   # the number of worker threads for write requests
> open_files_limit = 65535
>   # to allow handlersocket to accept many concurrent
>   # connections, make open_files_limit as large as
>   # possible.
> ```
>
> Second, log in to mysql as root, and execute the following query:
>
> ```
> mysql> install plugin handlersocket soname 'handlersocket.so';
> ```

I agree @Your Common Sense that using a HandlerSocket is NOT even needed. Unless your a major corporation and every second counts.

---

The fastest, normal way to connect

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$db->query("...");
```

How much speed do you actually need? If you need corporate size speed, I can help you with HandlerSocket. My guess is that you'll be just fine with standard MYSQLi connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a *real* fast connection with mysql database, you may consider a [HandlerSocket](http://wk-photo.ru/en/events/view/handlersocket-protocol-explained/1/) solution.

Though I doubt you really need anything that is faster than just regular approach.

Comment: So what a handler socket is, is just installing something like MariaDB instead of using just default MySQL?